# If my character dies in one campaign can I use said character in a different campaign?

Tags: character-death

If D&D my character dies in one campaign, can I use said character in a different campaign with a different DM and story line?

Comment: Unless you're doing organised play like Adventurer's League or similar, there are no rules about character reuse.

Comment: What edition are you talking about? What sort of gameplay (specifically, are you talking about Adventurer's League)?

Answer (score 5):

Ask you “different DM” - it’s up to them what characters they allow.